# jqGrid row editing custom edit action tooltip

Tags: jqgrid

have you ever created any custom action on your jqGrid?

looking [at this example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html),  I realized custom action, even if their tooltip are something similar to a sequence of html space (`&nbsp` ...)

any tips?

EDIT: this is the code I developed:

```js
gridComplete: function () {
    if (grid.getGridParam('records') == 0) // are there any records?
        DisplayEmptyText(true);
    else
        DisplayEmptyText(false);

    var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) { 
        var cl = ids[i];

        ae = "<a id='modifica' href='#'><img src='../../../images/edit.png' alt='' width='16' /></a>";
        be = "&nbsp;<a id='assegnacamera' href='#'><img src='../../../images/key.png' alt='Assegna Camera' width='16' /></a>";
        se = "&nbsp;<a id='cancel' href='#'><img src='../../../images/delete.png' alt='Elimina prenotazione' width='16' /></a>";
        ce = "&nbsp;<a id='unassigncamera' href='#'><img src='../../../images/room_unassign.png' alt='Elimina assegnazione camera' width='16' /></a>";
        de = "&nbsp;<a id='noshow' href='#'><img src='../../../images/reservationnoshow.png' alt='' width='16' /></a>";

        grid.jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: ae + be + se + ce + de }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i just realized it depends on the &nbsp I inserted in the beginning of those strings. You have to use title attribute to make tooltip work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should include `title: false` in the column definition to have no standard tooltip. Then you can either define different `tilte` attributes for separate `<a>` elements or use `cellattr` to set custom value on the `title` attribute of the cell (the `<td>` element).